# How to get this generic package to compile

Tags: generics, package, ada

I have the program to where it is reading the generic package, but I cannot figure out what to do about the context clauses to get the numbers to print and/or be read in from the file. In the client program right now, I have that the Element_Type should be an integer, but all my declarations are of type element, how do I do anything with this when there is no Ada.Element_text_IO;
please let me know, I've been stuck for quite a while.

client program

```
WITH Ada.Text_IO; 
WITH Ada.Integer_Text_IO; 
WITH Ada.Float_Text_IO; 
WITH Min_Max;

PROCEDURE Min_Max_Average_File IS
------------------------------------------------------------------
--| Finds and displays the minimum, maximum, and average
--| of a list of data items; the data items are read from a file.                                   
------------------------------------------------------------------

package Grades is new Min_Max(Element_Type => Integer);
use Grades;



  NumValues:    Element;  -- input - the number of items to be averaged
  CurrentValue: Element;   -- input - the next data item to be added   
  Smallest:     Element;   -- output - minimum of the data values
  Largest:      Element;   -- output - maximum of the data values
  Average:      Element;   -- output - average of the data values
  Sum:          Element;   -- program variable - the sum being accumulated   
  TestScores:   Ada.Text_IO.File_Type; 

BEGIN  -- Min_Max_Average_File
  -- Open the file and associate it with the file variable name
  Ada.Text_IO.Open
    (File => TestScores, Mode => Ada.Text_IO.In_File, Name => "scores.txt");

  -- Read from the file the number of items to be averaged
           Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(File => TestScores, Item => NumValues);  
           Ada.Text_IO.Put("The number of scores to be averaged is ");
           Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put(Item => NumValues, Width => 1);  
           Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
  -- Initialize program variables
  Smallest := Element'Last;
  Largest := Element'First;
  Sum := 0;

  -- Read each data item, log to the screen, add it to Sum, 
  -- and check if it is a new minimum or maximum
  FOR Count IN 1 .. NumValues LOOP
    Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(File => TestScores, Item => CurrentValue);
    Ada.Text_IO.Put("Score number ");
    Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put(Item => Count, Width => 1);  
    Ada.Text_IO.Put(" is ");
    Ada.Text_IO.Put(Item => CurrentValue, Width => 1);  
    Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
    Sum := Sum + CurrentValue;
    Smallest := Grades.Minimum(Value1 => Smallest, Value2 => CurrentValue);
    Largest  := Grades.Maximum(Value1 => Largest,  Value2 => CurrentValue);

  END LOOP;

  -- compute the average; since Sum and NumValues are integers,
  -- the average is truncated, that is, the fractional part is discarded
  Average := Sum / NumValues;

  -- display the results
  Ada.Text_IO.Put(Item => "The Smallest is ");
  Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put(Item => Smallest, Width => 1);  
  Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
  Ada.Text_IO.Put(Item => "The Largest is ");
  Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put(Item => Largest, Width => 1);  
  Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
  Ada.Text_IO.Put(Item => "The Average is ");
  Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put(Item => Average, Width => 1);  
  Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;

END Min_Max_Average_File;
```

package spec

```
generic

  Type Element_Type is private;


PACKAGE Min_Max IS

------------------------------------------------------------------
--| specifications of functions provided by Min_Max package                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------
  Type Element is new Element_Type;
  FUNCTION Minimum (Value1, Value2: Element_Type) RETURN Element_Type;
  -- Pre:  Value1 and Value2 have been assigned values
  -- Post: Returns the smaller of the two input values

  FUNCTION Maximum (Value1, Value2: Element_Type) RETURN Element_Type;
  -- Pre:  Value1 and Value2 have been assigned values
  -- Post: Returns the larger of the two input values
```

package body

```
PACKAGE BODY Min_Max IS
------------------------------------------------------------------
--| bodies of functions provided by Min_Max package                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------

  FUNCTION Minimum (Value1, Value2: Element_Type) RETURN Element_Type IS
    Result: Element_Type;
  BEGIN

    IF Value1 < Value2 THEN
       Result := Value1;
    ELSE
       Result := Value2;
    END IF;
    RETURN Result;

  END Minimum;

  FUNCTION Maximum (Value1, Value2: Element_Type) RETURN Element_Type IS
    Result: Element_Type;
  BEGIN

    IF Value1 > Value2 THEN
       Result := Value1;
    ELSE
       Result := Value2;
    END IF;
    RETURN Result;

  END Maximum;

END Min_Max;
```

Comment: This is all that I was given to work with, why should something else be there?

Comment: This is actually what I was given first, I added the type element, should I not have done that?

Comment: I do not understand. Where should I put this and I do not really know how to do this, the book I have is near useless for this problem

Comment: The program seems to cause less compile errors when type element is new Element_Type; is included.

Comment: I did not understand what you were saying, all i need this program to do is somehow change Ada.Integer_Text_IO and Ada.Float_Text_IO into something that works for my declared element

Comment: You do not have to show me on this program, but could you give me a visual example of what would need to be done

Comment: It is polite to think before you ask a question, and to try to make a minimal example of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to compile the specification for `Min_Max`, I get the error message:

```
min_max.ads:16:71: missing "end Min_Max;"
```

Fixing that should be quite trivial.

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
package Grades is new Min_Max(Element_Type => Integer);
```

this means that the functionality of `Grades` is that of `Min_Max`, **for `Integers`**.

So you shouldn’t declare `NumValues` etc. of type `Element`, but instead of type `Integer`. This will resolve your problems with being able to read/write values.

However, you will have problems compiling the generic. You’ve declared `Element_Type` as `private`; this restricts what you can do with objects of this type to *assignment* and *comparison for equality*. It does **not** support "<", "<=", ">=", ">".

If you’re happy to support signed integer types, you could say ([ARM 12.5.2(3)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-12-5-2.html#p3))

```
type Element_Type is range <>;
```

Alternatively (say you wanted to be able to support floating point types as well) you would need to import the relevant operations ([ARM 12.6(18)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-12-6.html#p18)):

```
type Element_Type is private;
with function "<" (L, R : Element_Type) return Boolean is <>;
with function ">" (L, R : Element_Type) return Boolean is <>;
```

(the `is <>` means to use the operation of `Element_Type` with the same name, if there is one).

Comment: Thank you for this, I needed it, but I still have another question if you'd be up for answering it. What if I wanted this to work for both integers and floats. Would I really need to go through and put if integer then if float then, or is there an easier way to do this